# Vaadin 8 Grid Layout remove excess space between row

Tags: java, css, gwt, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 GridLayout to display label and textfield and need to customize the spacing between cells. I tried the setSpacing function on the GridLayout, but the spacing between rows is way too much. I have attached a snapshot of the gridlayout with excessive vertical spacing between rows. I also, tried changing the css file but dint work.

```
gridLayout.setSpacing(true);

.mygrid .v-gridlayout-spacing-on 
{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
gridLayout.addStyleName("mygrid");
```

[image]

Appreciate if anyone could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way described on the [Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/5261573) is such as:

```
.mygrid .v-gridlayout-spacing-on {
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
}
```

I find this works to increase the spacing, but it couldn't reduce the gap by much.

This also works, but seems to offer better control over narrow spacings:

```
.mygrid .v-gridlayout-spacing-off {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px; 
}
```

- clearly with `gridLayout.setSpacing(false)` .

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, saved my day!!